# How to access objects from another thread android

Tags: android, multithreading

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 //new thread for communication. 
   Thread communicationThread = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
        Communication communication_object = new Communication();
        communication_object.start();
       }
   };

   communicationThread.start();     
    }
```

Communication class implements TCP/IP connection with server and works fine.

But now I need to access that communication object from another activity class - specifically login() method.
Can I access communication_object.login() running in that thread from another class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create a Thread and make it Singleton and/or do the same with an Object.

Since you can't serialize or put the Thread in a Bundle you'll store it outside the Activity if you want to access it from another activity.

You may also create a Singleton Thread within your MainActivity and access it using static methods.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public static Thread communicationThread = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 //new thread for communication. 
   communicationThread = new Thread() {
       public void run() {
        Communication communicationObject = new Communication();
        communicationObject.start();
       }
   };

   communicationThread.start();     
    }

 public static Thread getCommunicationThread() {
   if (communicationThread == null) { // init your Thread 
   } return communicationThread;   
}


public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    MainActivity.getCommunicationThread()...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So now to to access methods of that communication object from anothet activity, I would do something like MainActivitiy.getCommunicationThread().communication_object.method() ?

Comment: yup.  That's it. Youill get the Thread from the other activity. Better create a Singleton Factory (EG: SingletonPattern)

Comment: okay, it returns the thread from other activity as an object, but how do I enter that thread ? how can I run methods of the objects that has been initialised inside that thread ?